# Out of office reply not sending reply

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I have one user out of several who sets his out of office reply in Outlook/Outlook Web Access and when he receives an email the sender does not receive a reply.  Send to External senders is checked. Is there a good way to correct this?  This is on SBS 2008 and Exchange 2010.

Answer (score -1):

I ran outlook.exe /cleanrules   CAUTION: It wipes all of the rules.